# Ember Unexpected Token (In JSON at position 0)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Error:

```
Error while processing route: about Unexpected token < in JSON at 
position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have a feeling I know what's causing this error, but I can't seem to figure out how to serialize the data. Here is my data when I hit my API in postman:

```
[
  {
    "site_id": 1,
    "site_name": "example.com",
    "view_id": 136791757,
    "project_manager_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-19 02:52:15",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-19 02:52:15"
 },
 {
   "site_id": 2,
   "site_name": "example2.com",
   "view_id": 136903606,
   "project_manager_id": null,
   "created_at": "2017-10-19 04:12:58",
   "updated_at": "2017-10-19 04:12:58"
 }
]
```

Is the error I'm getting related to the fact that this response is in array form?? Do I need to serialize? If so, how?!

I did some Googling and this seems to be a somewhat common error, but could not find any Ember specific answers, so this could be helpful for others.

Thanks!!

Comment: Note: I may be totally off base on the serializer thing, could be something else that fixes this...

Comment: Default serializer is JSONAPI, do you have application.js file in serializers folder?. at the moment your response is not respecting both REST and JSONAPI format

Answer (score 1):

This means that the API did not respond with valid JSON. Check the network tab in Google Chrome and look at the output. Sometimes when you hit an API client side it isn't quite the same as when you hit it from Postman.

Comment: Good point, checked the network tab and for some reason its pluralizing the request URL like so: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/siteaccesses. Probably because I'm using findAll in the route. Thoughts?

Comment: The reason is that is the way Ember does it.  You can override the default behavior by implementing `pathForType` in a custom `Adapter`.  See: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization